# Proof Sequence Diverges

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the following sequence diverges to $+\infty$:

$$\left(\sqrt{4n^2+1}\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$$

Informal Thinking:

This is saying to show

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sqrt{4n^2+1}$

Want to show that $\sqrt{4n^2+1} > M$

Now $\sqrt{4n^2+1} > \sqrt{4n^3}$

$\sqrt{4n^3} > \sqrt{4N^3} = M \iff N = \frac{M^\frac{2}{3}}{2^\frac{2}{3}}$

We also need to $n$ to be positive, so let $N = \max\left\{0,\frac{M^\frac{2}{3}}{2^\frac{2}{3}}\right\}$

Proof:

Suppose $M \in R$ and let $N = \max\left\{0,\frac{M^\frac{2}{3}}{2^\frac{2}{3}}\right\}$

Then for all $n > N$, we have

$s_n = \sqrt{4n^2+1} > \sqrt{4n^3} > \sqrt{4N^3} \geq \sqrt{4\left(\frac{M^\frac{2}{3}}{2^\frac{2}{3}}\right)^3} = M^2$

This is not $M$ as desired and I'm not too sure why. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{4n^2+1}>\sqrt{4n^3}$? This inequality is not true for $n>1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to show that no matter how big an $M$ you pick, there is a point past which all the terms in the sequence are *bigger* than it. It doesn't have to be the most efficient $M$; any one will do, as long as this property is satisfied.

Note that:
$$
n^2 < 4n^2 + 1
$$

so that 
$$
n < \sqrt{4n^2 + 1}
$$

Therefore, whenever $n > M$, 
$$
M < \sqrt{4n^2 + 1}
$$

Thus for every $M$, there exists a point past which all terms $\sqrt{4n^2 + 1}$ exceed it, namely, the first integer above $M$ and all others after that.

Comment: Alright I see thanks